# xcode 9.2 pdf vector image corrupt under iOS 8.2 and below

Tags: ios, assets

after I update the xcode from 9.1 to 9.2, it gets no problem on iOS 8.3 and it's image broken under iOS 8.2 and below
[image]

Comment: see also https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/93743

Answer (score 1):

The images resources under custom bundle display ok, but in the assets display broken.

that is a bug by updating xcode from 9.1 to 9.2. It aspects the version under iOS 8.2 and below