# Images displayed fuzzy when building using xcode 9.2 vs xcode 9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, image

When I'm building my iOS app using xcode 9.2 the images are being displayed fuzzy when running on iOS 8.1. Building exactly the same app using xcode 9.0 images display correct on iOS8.1. (iOS9 and above are being displayed correctly)
Xcode 9.2:
[image]

Xcode 9.0:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47826794/4975761

Comment: thanks. looks like the same issue although he was complaining on vector images.